# How to get rid of the "click" sound at end of translation in Microsoft Translate API in Silverlight app

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, translation, wav

I am using the MS Translator to send back a WAV file of text to enable "talking" in my Silverlight 4 app.

However, at the end of every translation, there is a wierd click noise (it sounds like someone is turning a microphone on or off).

[Here is an online Silverlight app which demonstrates the issue](https://web.archive.org/web/20180206083504/http://timheuer.com:80/silverlight/translator-sample/). Type something in and translate it (can be the same language) and listen to the end of the talking.

Is there anything I can do to get rid of this noise? I was thinking of reading the WAV file to 90% and then stopping it before the sound but I would like to understand technically why it's coming back with the noise and where the problem is so I can find the best solution for it.

**UPDATE**: After Brad's useful lead below it seems that the problem is in the [WaveMediaStreamSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/gillesk/playing-back-wave-files-in-silverlight?PageIndex=1#comments) that converts the returned WAV into a format that Silverlight can use.

This is the same one mentioned/used in the [online project here](https://timheuer.com/blog/silverlight-translator-text-to-speech-api).

So... any idea how to get rid of the crackling sound when WaveMediaStreamSource converts it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is helpful, but it seems that the click noise isn't in the WAV file itself.

I used [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to dig out the response coming back from the server and saved that to a WAV file.  Opening that in [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/), I can clearly hear the translation to the end... no click.

So, that click might be the normal sound of the component in Silverlight stopping.  However, I have a different theory.

The WAV file itself is sampled at 8kHz.  That's kind of an oddball.  I bet the click noise is an artifact of the sound card or software (silverlight/audio driver/windows itself, etc.) up-sampling to a more appropriate rate.  This is testable.  Try making a WAV file and use Fiddler or some other HTTP proxy tool to return your WAV instead of what was requested from the Microsoft server.  See if your WAV (at 44.1kHz for example) has the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Brad, it's a lead - can you give me some tips on what you mean by retuning the different WAV file in Fiddler? Is this different to just embedding the sound in your SL app and playing it with a MediaElement?

Comment: Ok, I figured out what you meant - by saving the Response body in Fiddler you have the 8khz wav file which, as you pointed out, does NOT have the crackle at the end. I've dug deeper into the code and added some points to my original post (I think it is the WaveMediaStreamSource that is doing it then, but I still don't know how to fix it!)

Comment: Interesting.  Unfortunately, I've never coded for Silverlight before, so I don't have any way of helping further.  Again, I would look into what happens when the audio stops.  If the sample rate suddenly changes while playback is still happening, then there might be an issue.

Comment: Also, I used to have trouble in other .NET applications where the garbage collector would collect the resources for my WAV in memory while it was playing.  This would lead to nasty noises, as the buffer was just random bits in memory.  Maybe that is what is happening to you, but only for a short period of time.  Try making your variables for the WaveMediaStreamSource, and the resource actually being played, globals.  Or at least, in a class that isn't going away.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. I'm sure everyone does. Here is how I solved it.

Basically I added a marker to the stream that performed the callback 1 second before the audio was finished playing. That callback then fires a timer that is called 700ms later and that method stops the audio (about 300ms) before it's completed. I tried it without this timer and it was inconsistent. It seems like if you set a marker to fire 300ms before the end it wont always fire. Better to get it one second before and then run your own timer to cut it off when you are ready.

Here is the relevant code snippets. Hope it can help someone else. There are loads of other tricks to writing a smooth running audio player but this code should solve at least your clicking issue.

```
    public void Page_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {

        mediaElement.MediaOpened += new RoutedEventHandler(mediaElement_MediaOpened);
        mediaElement.MarkerReached += new TimelineMarkerRoutedEventHandler(mediaElement_MarkerReached);
    }



   Timer t;
    void mediaElement_MarkerReached(object sender, TimelineMarkerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // almost completed playing the file so lets stop before the annoying click is heard
        t = new Timer(handleStopTimerDone, "", 700, 0);
    }

   public void handleStopTimerDone(object state)
    {
        // stop the audio playing
        Stop();
    }




    private void mediaElement_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan duration = mediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan;
        TimelineMarker newMarker = new TimelineMarker();
        newMarker.Time = new TimeSpan(duration.Ticks - 10000000);
        while (mediaElement.Markers.Count > 0)
        {
            mediaElement.Markers.RemoveAt(0);
        }
        mediaElement.Markers.Add(newMarker);


    }


    public void Stop()
    {

            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
            {
                mediaElement.AutoPlay = false;
                mediaElement.Stop();
                mediaElement.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
                if (memData != null)
                {
                    WaveMediaStreamSource wavMss = new WaveMediaStreamSource(memData);
                    mediaElement.SetSource(wavMss);
                }
            });
    }
```